# Phone occasionally makes a beep

Tags: notifications, audio

I recently switched from iOS to Android, and I'm a bit unfamiliar with the new environment.

My phone is a Huawei Honor 8, and I upgraded to [EMUI 5.0](http://emui.huawei.com/en/) (thus, Android 7.0). I learned how to control the notification settings for individual apps:

[image: notification settings]

The icon of any app, which makes a notification sound, appears in the notification area. There, I can press-and-hold the notification to access its settings:

[image: notification area]

At least, that's what I expect! However, occasionally (once or twice a day), my phone makes a beep (like an alert, a notification sound, whatever), but no notification appears in the notification area.

I don't know which app is making this sound, and what is the reason behind it.

> Is there a way to find this out?
>   Say, is there a way to keep track of apps accessing the phone speaker?

Comment: Battery notification sounds?  Any health/fitness apps that are prompting you to "get up and move" or anything?  Without knowing what is all installed on your device, it really is hard to say what it could be specifically.

Comment: @RMarkwald: Perhaps [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can help. I'm looking into it...

Comment: Similar problems: [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-samsung-galaxy-s4/285600-random-sound-out-any-notifications.html) and [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/282858-2-tone-beep-sound-constantly-playing.html).